# Saving contents of imageContext?

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics

my project is to create a heat map app. In order to access the heat map of previously recorded teams, I need to know how to save drawings that I made using image context.

```
- (void)drawRect
{
    CGFloat dashes[2] = {25,25};

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.field.frame.size);
    [self.field.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.field.frame.size.width, self.field.frame.size.height)];
    if([_diagramselect selectedSegmentIndex]==3){
        CGContextSetLineDash(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0,dashes, 2);
    }
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), startlocation.x-56, startlocation.y-92);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), endlocation.x-56, endlocation.y-92);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapSquare);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush );
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    self.field.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

How can I save what I've drawn on top of a field image to access later? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create image ref from context.

```
CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked];
```